# Making Admob Native express ad dynamic

Tags: android, admob

I am integrating Admob Native express ad in my application. I want it to show in all size of devices. In small devices it is not showing because of ad size. My add is in listview and gridView.
     Please suggest me, how it will load add in each size of device. Even I was trying to set size dynamically, but did not Work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if you think it is.

Answer (score 6):

I had success with the following code:

```
private LinearLayout mAdContainer;
private NativeExpressAdView mAdmobAdView;
private AdRequest mAdmobAdRequest;

[...]

private void loadAds() {
    // find out the width of the device in dp
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float deviceWidthInDp = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;

    int adWidth = (int)(deviceWidthInDp);

    if (mAdmobAdView != null) {
      // prevents a crash on older devices
      mAdmobAdView.clearAnimation();
    }
    mAdContainer.removeAllViews();
    mAdmobAdView = new NativeExpressAdView(this);
    mAdmobAdView.setAdSize(new AdSize(adWidth, 250)); // AdSize(width, height), height ranges from 80 to 1200
    mAdContainer.addView(mAdmobAdView);
    mAdmobAdView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_id)); // set your admob id
    mAdmobAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    mAdmobAdView.loadAd(mAdmobAdRequest);
}
```

EDIT: thanks to [fattire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3035127/fattire) for pointing out to clear the animation before removing the view to prevent a crash on older devices (see [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=417271))

Comment: When implementing did you encounter an error code 1..
using the same approach but no luck

Comment: I did not encounter any error. I don't think Error Code 1 is related to this at all. Did you add the right AdUnitId?

Comment: thank you for your reply.. indeed, it was a stupid copy/paste mistake for the ad unit Id.. thanks again

Comment: It may be wise to `.clearAnimation()` from the NativeExpressAdView prior to removing it as some older kitkat-era webviews may crash with a `NullPointerException` at `com.android.webview.chromium.DrawGLFunctor.requestDrawGL(DrawGLFunctor.java:68)` if you don't.  See [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=417271).