# Admob NativeExpressAdView only java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

Any way to use `NativeExpressAdView` from admob without using a layout file (xml).

I use only java file to create views and am wondering on how to create a view from java file for `NativeExpressAdView` ?

**Edit:**

I tried this

```
NativeExpressAdView adView = new NativeExpressAdView(activity);
AdSize adSize = new AdSize(280, 80);
adView.setAdSize(adSize);
adView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, adSize.getHeightInPixels(activity));
adView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(request);

linear_layout.addView(adView);
```

this code give me a black empty view `width:280dp, height: 80dp`

Comment: @sanastasiadis, I edit the question, see the code that i tried, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work....  First "reserve" an id for the view by creating a file `/res/values/ids.xml`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
     <item name="nativeExpressAdId" type="id"/>
 </resources>
```

On API versions of Android > 17 you can [generate the ID on the fly](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId()), but then you lose backward compatibility.

Next add an entry to '/res/values/strings.xml`:

```
     <string name="adUnitId">ca-app-pub-12345678901234567890etc</string>
```

Then in code:

```
 NativeExpressAdView adView = new NativeExpressAdView(this);
 adView.setId(R.id.nativeExpressAdId);
 int height = 80; // or whatever is appropriate - make sure its >= ad minimum
 // set the size to the width of the screen
 adView.setAdSize(new AdSize((int) (AdSize.FULL_WIDTH, height));
 adView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.adUnitId));
 // assuming this goes in a linearlayout... you can also addRules to lp
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new 
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
 // set margins manually (`.setMargins()`) or add rules with (`.addRule()`)
 // or .setVisibility() etc... to lp
 adView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Then use `parent.addView(adView)` to insert this to the parent container.   This isn't exactly the code I've used (I was using a RelativeLayout), but it's pretty close, so should get you started.

This sort of code is kind of useful if you need to generate a new ad when rotating, since you can't resize an existing one.  You can "borrow" the previous ID, visibility, layout, etc. from the previous one and just apply it to the new one.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38029365/making-admob-native-express-ad-dynamic) for a similar example.

Tip:  Make sure to stop any running animations before removing a nativeexpressadview as this may cause crashes in older webviews like those found in kitkat.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much simlar to other but the width and height matters also you need a AdRequest

```
NativeExpressAdView mNativeExpressAdView = new NativeExpressAdView(this;
mNativeExpressAdView.setLayoutParams(new NativeExpressAdView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
mNativeExpressAdView.setAdSize(new AdSize(AdSize.FULL_WIDTH, 132)); // here 132 is the medium size

mNativeExpressAdView.setAdUnitId("YOUR AD_UNIT ID");
AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();

//adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice("28776EC697A5120CBA87CB573E26544A"); //if needed

<parent view>.adcontainer.addView(mNativeExpressAdView);
mNativeExpressAdView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Yeah sorry I assumed the adRequest and loadAd() was a given.. just wanted to show the layout part...